# Why does MS SQL CAST as bigint result in int overflow?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

Why does the following T-SQL statement:

```
select CAST(COALESCE('3537601039',0) as bigint)
```

result in the following error when run against MS SQL Server 10?

> The conversion of the varchar value '3537601039' overflowed an int
>   column.

Is there a "more correct" way to do this conversion of a `varchar` to a `bigint` that would avoid this problem when the number is within range of a `bigint`?

Comment: Why are you using `COALESCE` with static non-null values anyway?

Comment: @DStanley - Inherited system.  If I stopped to ask "why" with everything I find I wouldn't be able to keep it working ;)

Comment: Well you could take it out and you'd be fine - `select CAST('3537601039' as bigint)`

Comment: @DStanley - Oh, I see what you meant.  In implementation it's a param, not a static value.  Here I just provided a value that gave unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that is happening is that your string is trying to convert to a regular int to match the 0.  Try this:

```
select CAST(COALESCE('3537601039','0') as bigint)
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that putting the unqualified zero in the `coalesce` is implying a conversion to a smaller int before it is explicitly recast to a `bigint`.

The following simple change to make it a `coalesce` of string values solves the problem:

```
select CAST(COALESCE('3537601039','0') as bigint)
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast first, then do ISNULL

```
select ISNULL(CAST('3537601039' as bigint), 0)

select ISNULL(NULLIF(ISNULL(CAST('3537601039' as bigint), 0), 0), 1) + 3537601039
```

sql server firstly discovers `isnull(string, numeric)` and that numeric zero is by default `int`. So it tries to convert that string containing bigint to int. You were trying to cast to bigint too late.

another try:

```
select ISNULL('3537601039', 100000000000)
```